# Solve this system of equations without calculator

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

$$2a +4b +3c +5d +6e=37$$
$$4a +8b +7c +5d +2e=74$$
$$-2a -4b +3c +4d -5e=20$$
$$a +2b +2c -d +2e=26$$
$$5a -10b +4c +6d +4e=24$$

find $a,b,c,d,e$

I tried solving the system of equations above but ended up with many fractions and decimals that I could not solve it by hand. Is there a shortcut or trick to solving this easily by hand?

Comment: Did you try Gaussian Elimination?

Comment: @Moo, I tried Guassian Elimination.

Comment: I ended up with a lot of fractions and decimals with were difficult to calculate on without a calculator.

Comment: Since the solution to the system is $(a,b,c,d,e) = (-\tfrac{8221}{4340},\tfrac{8591}{8680},\tfrac{4695}{434},-\tfrac{459}{434}, \tfrac{699}{434})$, it is highly unlikely that there exists a "nice" way to solve the system.

Comment: The determinant of the matrix is $8680 = 2^3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot31$. So don't expect solutions to have an easy form.

Answer (score 1):

use forth equation to eliminate a and b simultaneously from first three equations. Now the first three euqations all have -c in each equation. Then you eliminate c from first two. Now you are almost there.